# BeautifulSoup -Retrieve only certain class contents within the same class

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

```
<div class = "MyClass"> ClassA </div>
    <table class = "Contents">
     ...contents that I want  
     <tbody>
     <tr class = "Header1"> x1 </tr>
          <th class = "Subheader"> Key1 </th>
          <th class = "Subheader"> Key2 </th>
     <tr class = "Data1"> x2 </tr>
          <th class = "Inside-Subheader"> Value1 </th>
          <th class = "Inside-Subheader"> Value2 </th>
<div class = "MyClass"> ClassB </div?
     <table class = "Contents">
     ...contents that I Do not Want
```

I am trying to get the "contents that I want" by doing this:

```
#looping through each link
myDict = defaultdict()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(subPages.content, "lxml")
    test = soup.find_all('tr',{'class' : 'ClassA'})[0]
    for k,v in myDict:
        # k['test']???
```

By doing this I can only access x1 but not x2. 
I also want to put it in a dictionary so that Value1 and Value2 corresponds to Key1 and Key2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it has a nested table: You can extract (remove from the soup) the nested table first then access the data you want in the normal way.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class = "MyClass"> ClassA </div>
<table class = "Contents">
 ...contents that I want
 <tbody>
 <tr class = "Header1"> x1 </tr>
      <th class = "Subheader"> Key1 </th>
      <th class = "Subheader"> Key2 </th>
 <tr class = "Data1"> x2 </tr>
      <th class = "Inside-Subheader"> Value1 </th>
      <th class = "Inside-Subheader"> Value2 </th>
<div class = "MyClass"> ClassB </div>
 <table class = "Contents">
 ...contents that I Do not Want
 <tbody>
 <tr class = "Header1"> x1 </tr>
      <th class = "Subheader"> Key1 </th>
      <th class = "Subheader"> Key2 </th>
 <tr class = "Data1"> x2 </tr>
      <th class = "Inside-Subheader"> Value1 </th>
      <th class = "Inside-Subheader"> Value2 </th>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# remove the nested table first.
elem =  soup.find_all('table')[1]
elem.extract()
elem =  soup.find('table')
keys =[i.text for i in elem.find_all('th', {'class': 'Subheader'})]
vals = [j.text for j in elem.find_all('th', {'class': 'Inside-Subheader'})]
myDict = dict(zip(keys, vals))
print (myDict)
```

Outputs:

```
{' Key2 ': ' Value2 ', ' Key1 ': ' Value1 '}
```

If the table is not nested you can remove the two lines:

```
elem =  soup.find_all('table')[1]
elem.extract()
```

Assuming it is the first table you want the code will just work otherwise use where 1 is the index of the table you want:

```
 elem =  soup.find_all('table')[1]
```